# Filtering which items to show up in collection field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form using this class type:

```php
class DespesasContainerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('despesas', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new DespesasFamiliasType(),
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))
        ;
    }

    // ...
}
```

This way it shows all items in the `despesas` attribute of the object.

Is there a way to filter which items to use? Something similar to the `query_builder` option on the `entity` field type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way from FormTypeInterface, but you can filter this collection before passing it to the Form.

Another tricky tip :

Define a public getter like `getFilteredDespeas` on your Entity that returns the filtered list of despeas. In your Form, just call the field  `filteredDespeas` instead of `despeas`. This involves that you specifically manage the form binding, by adding a public `setFilteredDespeas` to your entity, or any other way...